# Reading coordinates from txt into array (c#)

Tags: c#, arrays, coordinates, readline

My aim is to read txt file which contains number of coordinates (mentioned in the 1st line) and X Y values(double). for example:

> 2
>
> 4.454 3.24
>
> 1.23 4

I need to put these coordinates into array (without the 1st line)
so far I succeeded to read the text but don't how to put into the array.
my array is a Point (double x,double y) C'tor but I would like to learn how to put into normal array.
another question is how can I control which line I'm gonna read?

Is the code so far

```
       using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(fileName)) 
        {
            int i = 0;
            string inputLine;
            int len = int.Parse(inputLine = sr.ReadLine());
            string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
            foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(fileName))
            {
                string[] parts = line.Split(' ');
                foreach (string part in parts)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}",i, part);    
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
```

Thanks all!
p.s my 1st question, hope not violating forum's rules.

Comment: Can you give multiple line of your text
Also can you hint what should be the result

Comment: Really shouldn't open a `StreamReader` on the file and then use `File.ReadAllLines`.  You should use one or the other.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
var points = File.ReadLines("c:\filepath")
    .Skip(1) //Ignore the 1st line
    .Select(line => line.Split(' ')) //Chop the string into x & y
    .Select(split => new Point(double.Parse(split[0]), double.Parse(split[1])); //create a point from the array
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var coordinates = File.ReadLines(fileName).Skip(1)
                    .Select(line => line.Split())
                    .Select(x=>new PointF(float.Parse(x[0]),float.Parse(x[1])))
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: L.B & @DaveBish I'm a beginner and the syntax of ".Select" isn't allowed in that assignment. Is there other option with the use of only ReadLine,StreamReader,Split,Spare(string to double), Point array/foreach?

Comment: @DimaB Of course it is possible, but I don't want to make your assignment. There are many docs about those methods on the internet.